# Cannot generate frames containing a single image

Tags: beamer, graphics, includegraphics

I am trying to generate a sequence of frames conatining an image each. 
Overleaf gives the following error, which I cannot interpret.
The command works properly in other slides where I also inserted text

```
Missing number, treated as zero.

<to be read again> 
                   ]
l.145 \end{frame}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
```

And here is my code, which should be testable

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={table,dvipsnames},t]{beamer}
\usetheme{UCBerkeley}
\newtheorem{myth}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{myprop}{Proposition}[section]
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{sperner_graph_1.PNG}[width=0.33\linewidth]
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{sperner_graph_2.PNG}[width=0.33\linewidth]
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{sperner_graph_3.PNG}[width=0.33\linewidth]
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{sperner_graph_4.PNG}[width=0.33\linewidth]
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The optional argument is in the wrong place. It should be directly after includegraphics.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This is also true for `\newtheorem`.

Answer (score 1):

You systematically misplace the optional argument, both in `\newtheorem` and in `\includegraphics`, i.e. the argument in square brackets. That is,

```
\newtheorem{myth}{Theorem}[section]
```

needs to become

```
\newtheorem{myth}[section]{Theorem}
```

and

```
 \includegraphics{sperner_graph_1.PNG}[width=0.33\linewidth]
```

has to be

```
  \includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{sperner_graph_1.PNG}
```

Unfortunately I do not have the Berkeley theme, and not your graphics but the following works:

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={table,dvipsnames},t]{beamer}
%\usetheme{UCBerkeley}
\newtheorem{myth}[section]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{myprop}[section]{Proposition}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```